# Need to read a text file of size greater than 5 GB in chunks to reduce processing time using C++

Tags: c++, fstream, chunks

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){    
    string lineValue;
    ifstream myFile("file.txt");
    if (myFile.is_open()) {

        while (getline(myFile, lineValue)) {
            cout << lineValue << '\n';
        } 
        myFile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

1. Want to read the file in chunks.
2. The chunk that I've just read should go further for parsing.
3. In the meantime another chunk should be read.

How should I do this?

Comment: The code is just a generic example of "reading a file line by line" and does not document any thoughts you've invested into the field of multithreading.

Comment: You might want to look up 'double buffering' (or ['multiple buffering'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)) since that's what you seem to be wanting to do.

Answer (score 0):

A kind of solution to this (reading a file line by line and passing the lines to threads) can be found under [Message passing between threads using a command file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924588/message-passing-between-threads-using-a-command-file/26926927#26926927). The efficiency however depends on the complexity of tasks for the worker threads. Sometimes the file I/O buffering already is efficient enough to compensate for I/O latency.